# Touchpad won't work on Win 10

Tags: touchpad, windows-10-upgrade, asus-laptop

I have just upgraded to Windows 10. Since the upgrade, my touchpad won't work at all (an external mouse does work, but the touchpad doesn't respond). I'm using an ASUS X200L laptop. I tried searching but couldn't find any proper drivers on ASUS's website. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find any evidence of a `ASUS X200L` laptop on the ASUS Support website.  I was able to find existence of the following models.

- X200LA
- X200MA
- X200CAP
- X200CA

[I used that knowledge to determine your device likely is considered to be compatible with Windows 10.](http://www.asus.com/event/2015/osupgrade/upgrade.html)  You should be able to use the drivers from the [X200CA](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/X200CA/HelpDesk_Download/) to find the [V4.0.5 ASUS Smart Gesture drivers](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/Apps_for_Win10/SmartGesture/SmartGesture_WIN10_64_VER405.zip).

I have confirm all 4 of those listed device have the same version of the driver.  So it is a safe bet that it will work with the `X200L` which likely only has a different model number because of the region it is sold in.